# Issue implementing Google +1 button

Tags: php

I try to implement a Google +1 button in my website, but for some reason, I get the red exclamation mark as error...

And the weird part is the following. This snippet works perfect:

```
<span class="st_plusone" st_url="http://www.google.com/"></span>
```

But when I fill in my own URL, it goes wrong...

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

$url= curPageURL();
$st_spans .= "<span class=\"st_plusone\" st_url=$url></span>";
```

What am I doing wrong to get this +1 thing working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself. Apparently, dev sites aren't allowed in the URL :
So, `dev.mysite.com` isn't allowed, but `www.mysite.com` is!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the code provided by google to add the button to your site?

Check the info here:

http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/